# Kinda-mass emailing from Rails, but with own mail server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, mailchimp

I've read most of the other answers on this topic, but a lot of them related to either third-party services like MailChimp (which I'm not necessarily opposed to) or how not to upset the host's email server.

I believe this case is unique so that it'll contribute...

I have my own DigitalOcean droplet running a rails app.  I need to send out 100-1000 emails every so often, each with a unique message (a link I'm using for tracking clicks originating from the email).

I'm also operating my own iRedMail server.

Can someone recommend how to best-handle this task?  I was going to simply cycle through the list of emails and use the template.html.erb to drop in my link, but what types of problems might I run into?

Thank you!

Comment: Which MTA/email server do you intend to use? [sendmail/postfix/exim/...] In sendmail case you will need some minor customization of the configuration to avoid system overload by one+ process  per every email message send in burst.

Answer (score 0):

You should decouple your Rails App from the mail sending so that you don't have to wait in your view for the mails to be sent (assuming that you click on something that triggers the start of your mail sending). Use something like [delayed_job](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job) or another queueing mechanism that Rails offers and only queue up the sending job of the e-mails. Then when the queue comes to execute the particular job you can customize the message with an HTML part and a text part or whatever else you need and pass them on individually to your MTA.